# Cannot get variable to update in IF/Else statement based on page class

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript

I am trying to dynamically update a variable in a link depending on the page class, but I cannot seem to get the variable `ebox` to update in the if/else statement below.

At present the variable is always `0`, which is how it is initialised. I have implemented the code <s>[here](https://sitewidedesign.co.uk/pancake/)</s> and set up page classes for the `home`, `about` and `contact` pages as per the code below.

However the `ebox` value never becomes the intended `1`, `2`, or `3`.

Any suggestions as to what I am missing?

```
<?php 
$menu  = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive();
$class = $menu->params->get('pageclass_sfx');
?>

<script>
    var pageclass = "'<?php echo $class ;?>'";
    var ebox = 0;
    document.write(pageclass, ebox);

    if (pageclass == "home") {
        ebox = 1;
    } 
    else if (pageclass == "about") {
        ebox = 2;
    }
    else if (pageclass == "contact") {
        ebox = 3;
    }

    document.write('<a class="btn" data-ebox="' + ebox + '" href="#">Menu</a>');
    document.write(pageclass,ebox);
</script>
```

Comment: ... [Lodder never recommended the single quotes](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22694/12352).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your `pageclass` value is being declared as `'home'` (single-quoted), but you intend for it to be `home`. Just remove the single quotes, like this:

```
var pageclass = "<?php echo $class; ?>";
```

This syntax provides the same effect with improved brevity:

```
var pageclass = "<?=$class?>";
```

See this post regarding [PHP short tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1386620/2943403).